# Nested dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

**Scenario:** From my previous question ([Organizing pythonic dictionaries for a JSON schema validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55243017/organizing-pythonic-dictionaries-for-a-json-schema-validation)), I am now trying to create my dictionaries in a more efficient manner. Instead of feeding all the information at once to the dictionary, I am trying to pass it step by step.

**What I have so far:**

```
cldr["holidays"] = {"type": "object",
                    "description": "Holiday specification",
                    "properties": {
                            "default":{
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "description": "Calendars used",
                                    "properties":{
                                            "ref": {"type": "string"},
                                            "type": {"type": "string"},
                                            "value": {"type": "string"}
                                            }
                                        },                                   
                            "exante": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "description": "Calendars used",
                                    "properties":{
                                            "ref": {"type": "string"},
                                            "type": {"type": "string"},
                                            "value": {"type": "string"}
                                            }
                                        },                                     
                            "expost": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "description": "Calendars used",
                                    "properties":{
                                            "ref": {"type": "string"},
                                            "type": {"type": "string"},
                                            "value": {"type": "string"}
                                            }
                                        },                                        
                                    } 
                   }
```

**What I am trying to do:**

```
cldr["holidays"] = {"type": "object",
                    "description": "Holiday specification",
                    "properties": {"default", "exante", "expost"}
                    }

cldr["holidays"]["properties"]["default"] = {
                                "type": "object",
                                "description": "",
                                "properties":{
                                        "ref": {"type": "string"},
                                        "type": {"type": "string"},
                                        "value": {"type": "string"}
                                        }
                                    }
cldr["holidays"]["properties"]["exante"] = {
                                "type": "object",
                                "description": "",
                                "properties":{
                                        "ref": {"type": "string"},
                                        "type": {"type": "string"},
                                        "value": {"type": "string"}
                                        }
                                    }
cldr["holidays"]["properties"]["expost"] = {
                                "type": "object",
                                "description": "",
                                "properties":{
                                        "ref": {"type": "string"},
                                        "type": {"type": "string"},
                                        "value": {"type": "string"}
                                        }
                                    }
```

But that yields the following error:

```
TypeError: 'set' object does not support item assignment
```

**Question1:** Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

**Question2:** Would it be possible to create a shared class for the inner parts of this dictionaries? Since they would be inherently the same, do I need to define each of them separately or is there a way to do it more efficiently?

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. `{"default", "exante", "expost"}` is a `set`, and `set` ≠  `dict`. And what makes you think this would be *more* efficient? Did you do any benchmarks?

Comment: This would be a dict  {"default":None, "exante":None, "expost":None}

Comment: @meowgoesthedog My issue is that putting everything at once is very convoluted (IMO) and I end up making mistakes. Therefore I am trying to break it down to smaller parts.

Comment: @KennyOstrom So in this case, by just setting each of the inner parts to None, it avoids being a  `set` type?

Comment: Just do "properties": {} and it will default to an empty dict. You fill in the keys later, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What's wrong about this?**

You're mistakenly creating a set at the properties key.

```
cldr["holidays"] = {"type": "object",
                    "description": "Holiday specification",
                    "properties": {"default", "exante", "expost"} # creates a set
                    }

cldr["holidays"]["properties"]["default"] = {
                                "type": "object",
                                "description": "",
                                "properties":{
                                        "ref": {"type": "string"},
                                        "type": {"type": "string"},
                                        "value": {"type": "string"}
                                        }
                                    }
cldr["holidays"]["properties"]["exante"] = {
                                "type": "object",
                                "description": "",
                                "properties":{
                                        "ref": {"type": "string"},
                                        "type": {"type": "string"},
                                        "value": {"type": "string"}
                                        }
                                    }
cldr["holidays"]["properties"]["expost"] = {
                                "type": "object",
                                "description": "",
                                "properties":{
                                        "ref": {"type": "string"},
                                        "type": {"type": "string"},
                                        "value": {"type": "string"}
                                        }
                                    }
```

**Here's how you correct that**

Give the properties key a value that's an empty dictionary. When you do `cldr["holidays"]["properties"]["default"] = {the inner dictionary}`, you'll be setting the `default` key and its value..

```
cldr["holidays"] = {"type": "object",
                    "description": "Holiday specification",
                    "properties": {} # creates an empty dictionary
                    }

cldr["holidays"]["properties"]["default"] = {
                                "type": "object",
                                "description": "",
                                "properties":{
                                        "ref": {"type": "string"},
                                        "type": {"type": "string"},
                                        "value": {"type": "string"}
                                        }
                                    }
cldr["holidays"]["properties"]["exante"] = {
                                "type": "object",
                                "description": "",
                                "properties":{
                                        "ref": {"type": "string"},
                                        "type": {"type": "string"},
                                        "value": {"type": "string"}
                                        }
                                    }
cldr["holidays"]["properties"]["expost"] = {
                                "type": "object",
                                "description": "",
                                "properties":{
                                        "ref": {"type": "string"},
                                        "type": {"type": "string"},
                                        "value": {"type": "string"}
                                        }
                                    }
```

**What it sounds like you want**

```
def holiday_property():
    return {
             "type": "object",
             "description": "",
             "properties": {
               "ref": {"type": "string"},
               "type": {"type": "string"},
               "value": {"type": "string"}
             }
           }

cldr["holidays"] = {
  "type": "object",
  "description": "Holiday specification",
  "properties": {}
}
cldr["holidays"]["properties"]["default"] = holiday_property()
cldr["holidays"]["properties"]["exante"] = holiday_property()
cldr["holidays"]["properties"]["expost"] = holiday_property()
```